# How can I compress or convert wav file before or after upload to server

Tags: node.js, audio, compression

I'm using Nodejs and React.

I need to record user voice message and save it to server for later.
Currently I'm getting file size of 400kb for 5 sec of audio.
I'm getting blob and convert it to base64 and upload it to server where it's saved to file as that.

How can I reduce file size, compress it or something and later just link it to  without any need to uncompress on backend

Comment: What format/encoding is that audio file in? raw pcm? mp3?

Comment: currently it's audio/wav type and it's saved like that

Comment: Is it an option to use something like mp3 instead?

Comment: I just read mp3 size could be up to 10x smaller than wav.

Comment: Is there any other format for even more compression that i can link directly to <source/>

Comment: MP3 is the best option that is supported in all major browsers.